# webkit redirect to blank page with javascript content

Tags: javascript, html, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form contain textarea to write some HTML to store in database and render later.
It works for all content including javascript code inside the textarea.
However, when the code contain

```
self.location.href
```

after save, it will redirect to a blank page.
This only happen in webkit browser such as safari and chrome
firefox and even IE do not have this problem.

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The keyword `self.location` is supported by all browsers, but not in standard way

if you want to do this use `this.location` or `document.location` to check that it affects or not.

This should do, if NOT,

The problem might be the return value, as browser webkit does not return value true/false with self.location so you need to add a code to that which will return false manually..

Note: Please provide your work/ code for better understanding of problem.

Edit: Clarification on problem with the input and button.

I have updated [`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/v7VKC/1/) for you, please check reply if any doubt.

Comment: Sorry for mis-leading. A form with some textfield which allow to input javascript, after save, the system will show the form again, however, the javascript "self.location.href=''" in the hidden field, will get fired, cause the browser jump to a blank page. This only happened in webkit browser

Comment: if possible go to `jsfiddle.net` and create a fiddle with your code sample and then post the link that will help in best way. :)

Comment: @AlanChan if seems you are not able to create fiddle, please see the updated answer with fiddle, and reply :)